# ImageLoader UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default

Tags: android

Can someone give me idea how to put path of real device image folder in  **imageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(path, imageView, options);** . Because i pass the parameter with sd card image path but UniversalImageLoader   E/ImageLoader﹕ UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [/storage/emulated/0/classnkk_images/1_20150928163482053.png]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))

here is my Logcat

```
9-30 08:46:28.731  25090-25123/? E/ImageLoader﹕ UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [/storage/emulated/0/classnkk_images/1_20150928163491042.png]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [/storage/emulated/0/classnkk_images/1_20150928163491042.png]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(BaseImageDownloader.java:280)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:99)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:291)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:274)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:230)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-30 08:46:28.731  25090-25090/? E/sizeImgElement﹕ = 1_20150928163482053.png = 27021
09-30 08:46:28.740  25090-25090/? E/path﹕ = /storage/emulated/0/classnkk_images/1_20150928163482053.png
09-30 08:46:28.742  25090-25124/? E/ImageLoader﹕ UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [/storage/emulated/0/classnkk_images/1_20150928163482053.png]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [/storage/emulated/0/classnkk_images/1_20150928163482053.png]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(BaseImageDownloader.java:280)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:99)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:291)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:274)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:230)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `file://` scheme, as is shown in [the documentation](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#acceptable-uris-examples).

```
"file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png" // from SD card
```

Comment: But my image folder is in Internal Storage so how can i get the path , ImageLoader says no such file or directory .

Comment: @androidTag: "how can i get the path" -- given a `File` object named `f` pointing at the file, use `Uri.fromFile(f).toString()`.